# java Mybatis uses SQL @variables Execution error

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, mybatis

This SQL is to convert tool_ip_assigned the assigned field ID

The original SQL instructions can be executed normally

```sql
SET @num := 0;
UPDATE tool_ip_assigned SET id = @num := (@num+1);
ALTER TABLE tool_ip_assigned  AUTO_INCREMENT =1;
```

But changing to Mybatis execution will result in an error

```xml
<update id="reorder">
    SET @num := 0;
    UPDATE tool_ip_assigned SET id = @num := (@num+1);
    ALTER TABLE tool_ip_assigned  AUTO_INCREMENT =1;
</update>
```

error:

```
failed: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 

 ### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE tool_ip_assigned SET id = @num := (@num+1);

         ALTER TABLE tool_ip_a' at line 2

 ### The error may exist in URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/mapper/tool/IpAssignedMapper.xml]

 ### The error may involve defaultParameterMap

 ### The error occurred while setting parameters

 ### SQL: SET @num := 0;         UPDATE tool_ip_assigned SET id = @num := (@num+1);         ALTER TABLE tool_ip_assigned  AUTO_INCREMENT =1;

 ### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE tool_ip_assigned SET id = @num := (@num+1);

         ALTER TABLE tool_ip_a' at line 2

 ; bad SQL grammar []] with root cause

 

 java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE tool_ip_assigned SET id = @num := (@num+1);

         ALTER TABLE tool_ip_a' at line 2

    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:121) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]

    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]

    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]

    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.execute(ClientPreparedStatement.java:354) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]

    at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidPooledPreparedStatement.execute(DruidPooledPreparedStatement.java:483) ~[druid-1.2.16.jar!/:na]
...
```

I don't understand why this is happening. How can I modify it using Mybatis? The original SQL can be executed

I hope you can help me correct how to correctly execute on Mybatis

Comment: Try enabling [`allowMultiQueries`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-connp-props-security.html#cj-conn-prop_allowMultiQueries). It can usually be done by adding `?allowMultiQueries=true` (if it's the first property) or `&allowMultiQueries=true` to the JDBC connection URL.